# Android - findViewById() - passing argument to constructor

Tags: android, view, surfaceview

I created a class that inherits from SurfaceView. I would like to pass an argument to its constructor while calling findViewById(). Is it possible? How? How to handle it if not?

```
this.surfaceView = (TubeSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
```

Thank you.

Comment: `findViewById` doesn't construct anything. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You can get the view and then pass a reference to that to your class through its constructor, if that's what you are wanting

Comment: @TedHopp I would like to pass a Bitmap to be drawn in the TubeSurfaceView (on surfaceCreated()).

Comment: Then get your instance of Bitmap and create a constructor in the receiving class that accepts a bitmap object as a parameter

Comment: Define a bitmap setter method in your `TubeViewSurface` class. Then, after retrieving the view, just call the setter with the bitmap you want used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope.  findViewById is used on already instantiated views to find already instantiated children.  Either you need to create the surface view programatically (in which case you wouldn't need to call findViewById), or you need to make whatever you want to pass via constructor an xml parameter.